# access options .dbf file crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, dbf

I was hoping for some opinions could be provided on the following options to access .dbf via crystal? (Pros, Cons, examples or alternative methods)

From my testing thus far, there seems to several options for accessing .dbf files, some of which appear to be limited in either speed, indexing, or linking options.

Notes:

- Multiple tables, Each a unique .dbf file
- one to one and many to one relationships
- some index files available .idx files

Tables (say)
stock.dbf, sales.dbf, customers.dbf

---

Methods - Using data explorer
 1. (The most common method we have used) Find Database files.
 2. ODBC --> Visual FoxPro Tables --> Path_of_folder
 3. Import .dbf tables into SQL --> access directly via from database
 4. I was also thinking it may be possible to directly select the files via SQL or create a sql view of the files.
Something Like:

```
select * from OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0','dBase IV;
HDR=NO;IMEX=2 DATABASE=Path_of_folder','select * from
stock.dbf OUTER JOIN sales.dbf')
```

or

```
Select * from openrowset('VFPOLEDB','Path_of_folder\Stock.dbf';
'';'','select * from stock')
```

---

Results Testing:

Method 1

- Cannot create relationship links without indexes
- Links only on indexed fields
- Seems only to link only in the direction many to one (sales.dbf to stock.dbf) not one to many (stock.dbf to sales.dbf). [This becomes a problem if say a stock item has had no sales thus never appearing on the report]

Method 2

- Does not allow addition of indexes
- will allow either Left or Right outer joints
- Unproven it this is scanning correctly with multiple tables in use (I suspect not)

Method 3

- original .dbf files need updating regularly & import takes hours

Method 4

- Just a theory that data could be condensed via a view on the .dbf files (hopefully speeding up the process)

---

Thanks B

System Notes:
Crystal Reports 8.5 sp3    (We have tried, Crystal XI with these files & found database scanning problems)
Database:
Early version .dbf files (I'm told they are similar to dBase files)

Comment: Any compulsion to stick to .dbf files? It is not very suitable for reporting. You may look to have a process to create the reporting data into a separate .dbf file.

Comment: Compulsion = Making Do {95% functioning system + low budget} Vs a full new system {and the problems that come with it}